# How to create an AVD for "system-images;android-27;google_apis;x86" using avdmanager command line in Ubuntu?

Tags: android, command-line, android-emulator, avd-manager

I am able to create emulators for android-26 and older using the avdmanager command line, but I am getting the following error when trying to create for android-27 and above:

```
~/Android/sdk/tools/bin/avdmanager create avd --force -n Tablet -k "system-images;android-27;google_apis;x86" -d 6 --sdcard 200M
    Error: Package path is not valid. Valid system image paths are:ository...       
    system-images;android-26;google_apis;x86
    null
```

The same command for android-26 works:

```
~/Android/sdk/tools/bin/avdmanager create avd --force -n Tablet -k "system-images;android-26;google_apis;x86" -d 6 --sdcard 200M
```

Am I missing anything?

P.S.: This is happening in Linux Ubuntu. It seems to work fine in Mac OS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your command is correct but problem is that in your system, you don't have "android-27" OS

Please check which OS you have in your system, go into following directory

directory path : `~\Android\Sdk\platforms`

if you don't have it please download it first.

download command is : `sdkmanager --install "system-images;android-27;google_apis;x86"`

Comment: Thanks, @Parkash, for the answer. 
I have checked and it shows that I have it: 
`
~/Android/sdk/platforms/
 total 32
 drwxr-xr-x 8 user user 4096 Jul 31 11:51 ./ 
drwxr-xr-x 18 user user 4096 Jul 30 13:50 ../ 
drwxr-xr-x 5 user user 4096 May 5 2016 android-22/ 
drwxr-xr-x 6 user user 4096 Aug 7 2016 android-23/ 
drwxr-xr-x 6 user user 4096 Aug 7 2016 android-24/ 
drwxr-xr-x 6 user user 4096 Jan 12 2017 android-25/ 
drwxrwxr-x 6 user user 4096 Jul 30 11:54 android-26/ 
drwxr-xr-x 6 user user 4096 Jul 31 11:51 android-27/
`

Comment: `advmanager list avd` gives me an empty list of avds `Available Android Virtual Devices:`. The `avdmanager list target` gives me the platform that I want to create the emeulator:
`id: 6 or "android-27"
     Name: Android API 27
     Type: Platform
     API level: 27
     Revision: 3`

Comment: you have any information about ABI type ? "x-86" , "armeabi-v7a"

Comment: Please use following command :-

a.) ~/Android/sdk/tools/bin/avdmanager create avd --force -n Tablet -k "system-images;android-27;google_apis;x86" -d 7 --sdcard 200M

b.) ~/Android/sdk/tools/bin/avdmanager create avd --force -n Tablet -k "system-images;android-27;google_apis;x86"

Comment: Thanks for your help. I figured that my Linux machine was missing the package. android-27 was partially installed. By running `sdkmanager --install "system-images;android-27;google_apis;x86"` fixed the problem